# Recursive search function for windows dictornaries. How?

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion, javafx

I have an assignment where I have to use a recursive method to find any file in the dictionary i "stand in right now". The dictionary is shown in a listview and you can navigate back and forth through the folders in the GUI

Example: If i stand in C:/User/Me/ in the dictionary navigator in my GUI and then I type "hello" in the textfield of my gui, then the program must search for a file named "hello" in -> C:/User/Me/. I tried to solve the problem but ended up in a big mess and now I need some help and guide

**The recurisve method that shall be used is this which work in console:**

```
public static String findHolger(File dir, String search) {

    if (dir.getName().contains((search))) {
        System.out.println(dir.getPath());
    }

    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // System.out.println(files[i]);

        if (files[i].getName().contains(search)) {
            System.out.println(files[i]);
        }
    }
    return search;
}
```

**This is what i have tried so far with anyout any succes:**

```
public void findholger() {
//this method executes when search button is pressed

File dir = new File("C:/");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
lvwMappesys.getItems().setAll(files);

    String result, q;

    q = txf.getSelectedText().trim();
    File file1 = lvwMappesys.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if (lvwMappesys.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getAbsolutePath() != null) {

    }

    File[] files = file1.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // System.out.println(files[i]);

        if (files[i].getName().contains(q)) {
            System.out.println(files[i]);
        }

        if (files[i].isDirectory()) {

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your `ListView` has items which are the directory names. So you take the selected item and obtain its absolute path as `Path` type. You can then do the following (Note: contains Java 8 code)

```
Files.walk(path)
     .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
     .filter(path -> path.toAbsolutePath().toString().contains("hello"))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will recursively search for files which have "hello" in their names or parent directory names. You can easily modify the `filter()` method to fit your needs, i.e. if you need files which are named "hello" but not the directory names, etc.